# Change font size without running into max 'Maximum update depth exceeded' in React

Tags: css, reactjs, react-dom

I have a div which has a specific height and width.

When placing text in this div, I want it to be just the perfect size. That means text is big enough to just fit in the div but will not overflow.

So my logic roughly goes like:

```
calculateFitAndOverflow(){
  // I do some div height and overflow calculations here
  return {
    fit: true, // or false
    overflow: false // or true
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
  var fit_and_overflow = this.calculateFitAndOverflow(); 
  this.setState(fit_and_overflow);
}

componentDidUpdate(){
  if(this.state.fit === false){
    var fit_and_overflow = this.calculateFitAndOverflow();
    this.setState(fit_and_overflow);
  }
}
```

This works well but runs into problems for some starting conditions.

When the initial font size is small and div is big, the `setState` has to get called **many** times that React prematurely throws a 'Maximum update depth exceeded'.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a better way to solve this problem without having to do the `render -> check height -> adjust -> render` cycle?
2. Can I stop React from throwing the error and have it continue?

Comment: where are you setting this.state.fit=true? componentDidupdate is being called endlessly because this.state.fit never becomes true.

Comment: I am indeed changing state.fit to true. Let me update the question with more info.

Comment: you don't need to compare boolean with boolean if(this.state.fit === false) can be if(!this.state.fit) if this doesn't work that means the fit is never being set to true.

Comment: That's a programming triviality and is not the real problem here. The code actually *runs*. So the fit never being set to true is incorrect. 
The real problem is that if I start at font-size 10px and have a big div whose ideal fit size is 50px, I'm rendering the component 40 times(incrementing it by 1 every time). That is a bad pattern and React doesn't like it.

Comment: then you need to share calculateFitAndOverflow logic.

Comment: Why dont you make use of css? I dont get  it ))

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing a binary search to find the font fit instead of linearly increasing font size by 1 which React was complaining about.

Turns out there is already a react library that was built for this very use case.
https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-textfit/blob/master/src/Textfit.js#L127

I borrowed the binary search idea and implemented it on my own.

Thank you everyone :)